# Which Purāṇas define the word "purāṇa" within their text?

Tags: puranas, name, padma-purana, vayupurana, etymology

From the [sample page](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/books-2015/nag680b.jpg) of this [book](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/critical-study-of-mahabhagavadpuranam-NAG680/):

---

> [image]

---

**Questions**:

1. Which all Purāṇas define the word 'purāṇa' within their text?
2. Can you cite the exact verses (and their translation) from each of the Purāṇas that give such a definition?

Answer (score 8):

Etymology of the word "purāṇa" is mentioned *Part 1 Prakriya Pada Chapter 1 of Vayu Purana*.

> यस्मात्पुरा ह्यनतीदं<sup>**1**</sup> पुराणं तेन तत्स्मृतम्। 
>  निरुक्तमस्य यो वेद
>   सर्वपापैः प्रमुच्यते।।२०३।।
>
> This is called Purana because it breathes (exists) from earliest
>   times. The etymology of this one (i.e. Purána) who knows, he gets rid
>   of all the sins.

Foootnotes say

1. ह्यनती = हि + अनति - from root अन to breathe, Vedic variant of अनिति  clasical. A practical Vedic dictionary by Dr. Surya Kanta, p. 27. Oxford University Press, Delhi 1981.

<sub>This answer will be updated with other references shortly</sub>.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer because you asked references and definition specifically from the Puranas only.

Anyways,why the Puranas are so-called is stated symbolically in the KulArnava TantrA as follows:

> **Punya PApAdi KathanaAd RAkshashA DinibAranAt| NavabhaktyAdi JananAt
> PurAn Iti Kathyate|(KulArnava TantrA ,17.39)**
>
> Because it tells of merit and demerit, Punyapapa, because it dispels
> evil beings like Raksasas, and because it generates ninefold devotion,
> Navabhakti, and the like, it is called Purana.

Comment: The "na" used in purana is ण and "na" used in navabhakthi is न.

Comment: It may be so..but this is what is stated in the text i mentioned..

Comment: @SreeCharan When the small na follows ra there is a rule that it changes to the big Na. @ Rickross interesting definition. What is the Kularnava Tantra?

Comment: @Surya Kularnava Tantra is a Shakta Agama..Thanks for pointing that  rule out..I think in bengali too we have a similar rule..

Comment: Thank you very much! That's not a def. which people often quote. But this is a very proper def., according to me.

Comment: No problem .. @Bingming